# Staple onto MyContent

Tags: feature, my-site, event-receivers, my-content

I made my farm level stapler and my site level staple features, for SPSPER#0 it fires on MySite creation, so I presumed SPSMSITEHOST#0 would be MyContent, but nothing gets fires at all.

I set the stapler for both templates to be sure but it only activates on SPSPER#0 on MySite and only updates the master page on MySite.

This is the first time we have had a client who wanted MyContent branding so we just aren't sure if we have the right template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check out the following codeplex project. It includes a VS2010 solution for branding My Site Content Sites.

http://sp2010mysite.codeplex.com/

You will want to feature staple to SPSPER#0, that is the site template that is used when a My Site Content site collection is created, i.e. once per user as each user gets their own My Site content site collection.

If you want to brand you my site host site simply open that in SPD and modify that site collection's branding. There is only one My Site Host site for each farm, all uses share this one site collection.

Comment: We did the actual mysite with the onet file since we are doing multi stage testing and re-wipes and tests on certain things. Now the problem is why is it opening up the mysite url when it fires as the feature parent?